# JavaFX - Modality "order"

Tags: javafx, dialog, modality

For locking a client application (after some time of user inactivity) I do popup a application modal dialog (Dialog class) which prevents all other user inputs and forces authentication which works just fine.

There is one problem with this approach. In case another modal dialog is triggered it is shown on top, steals the focus and so bypasses the locking mechanism.

Is there any approach to prevent additional modal dialogs to take control and leave the input to the "one and only master dialog"?

Comment: A better approach is too use StackPane which on top has a Region and a Form which requires Authentication.So whatever happens app will not be unlocked if not form is filled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think modal dialogs are still a problem. They could contain user actions which are not allowed in this state. I can't prevent them to be openend (e.g. triggered by a background task).

Comment: You can add a variable like Flag and when the Flag is true no pop ups can be shown.When you are done with your job you can reset it back to false.